# I want that the information of the shops will be viewed on the map

Tags: android, google-maps

```
public static ShopNearMeFragment newInstance() {
    ShopNearMeFragment fragment = new ShopNearMeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop_near_me, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    searchShops();
    getCars();
    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    return view;
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@OnClick({R.id.button3, R.id.button4})
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button3:
            searchShops();
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            ArrayList<String> checks = getChecks();

            try {
                JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
                obj.put("checks",new JSONArray(checks));
                obj.put("car",cars.get(spinnerCars.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                obj.put("issue",issue.getText().toString());
                obj.put("lat",latitude);
                obj.put("long",longitude);
                Utils.startActivity(getActivity(),ShopsActivity.class,obj.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 11
            );

        }
        return;
    }

    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        Log.i("onMapReady", "lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude);
        CameraUpdate center =
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude,
                        longitude));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);

        mMap.moveCamera(center);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Utils.showAlertDialog(getActivity(),"Please On location of you device.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mapView.onResume();
}

void searchShops() {
    try {
        mMap.clear();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DatabaseReference feedsRef = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).database.getReference("shops");
    feedsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.i("onDataChange", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            try {
                ArrayList<String> checks = getChecks();


                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(map);
                JSONArray filters=data.optJSONArray("type");

                boolean isAvailable=false;

                if(checks.size()==0){
                    setMarker(data.getDouble("latitude"), data.getDouble("longitude"), data.optString("name")
                            ,data.optString("address")+"\n"+data.optString("phone")
                                    +"\n"+data.optString("email"));
                    return;
                }

                for(int i=0;i<checks.size() && !isAvailable;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<filters.length() && !isAvailable;j++){
                        if(checks.get(i).equals(filters.getString(j))){
                            isAvailable=true;
                            setMarker(data.getDouble("latitude"), data.getDouble("longitude"), data.optString("name")
                                    ,data.optString("address")+"\n"+data.optString("phone")
                                    +"\n"+data.optString("email"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

@NonNull
private ArrayList<String> getChecks() {
    ArrayList<String> checks=new ArrayList<String>();
    if(tyreCB.isChecked()){
        checks.add("tyre");
    }
    if(engineCB.isChecked()){
        checks.add("engine");
    }
    if(batteryCB.isChecked()){
        checks.add("battery");
    }
    if(brakesCB.isChecked()){
        checks.add("brakes");
    }
    if(airconCB.isChecked()){
        checks.add("aircon");
    }
    if(needTwoningCB.isChecked()){
        checks.add("needtowning");
    }
    return checks;
}

private void setMarker(double lat, double longg, String placeName,String snippet) {

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(lat, longg)).title(placeName)
            .snippet(snippet);

    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    marker.showInfoWindow();
}

void getCars() {
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    cars=new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference feedsRef = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).database.getReference("cars");
    feedsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.i("onDataChange", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            try {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                JSONObject _data = new JSONObject(map);
                data.add(_data.optString("model"));
                cars.add(_data);
                spinnerCars.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

I want that the information of the shops will be viewed on the map and i dont know how.. im quite new in this platform and im not really familiar yet of the functionalities... 
i would like that the information of the shop will be viewed as i press on them

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUeMU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A nice example for custom InfoWindow http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html

or check this official documentation with an example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows